# Extract value given key for a single dictionary inside list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

So I have a list like the following

```
[{'id': '290910533794791424', 'invite': 'KEY', 'orderid': 'YMHBK8', 'order': 'specified value'}]
```

How would I obtain a certain value such as the `orderid`?

Comment: `my_data[0]['orderid']`. You have a dictionary that's wrapped in a list. If you want to be able to access it without that `[0]`, do `my_data = my_data[0]`, and then you can just use `my_data['orderid']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list containing a single dictionary.

Therefore, you can retrieve the value for a given key by either extracting the first element explicitly *or* iterating the list once:

```
lst = [{'id': '290910533794791424', 'invite': 'KEY',
        'orderid': 'YMHBK8', 'order': 'specified value'}]

res = next(iter(lst))['orderid']  # 'YMHBK8'
res = lst[0]['orderid']           # 'YMHBK8'
```